# trigger login window

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: login window]

I do a JQuery trigger on a login button to auto login.
It works fine in IE but in Firefox i get this login window.
My question is:

Can I trigger the click on OK with jQuery?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
              jQuery('.centerButton').trigger('click');
    });
```

Comment: @diEcho - this message box has noting to do with making it out of JavaScript. User is trying to avoid having to click the authentication message box's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is browser chrome and not part of the DOM so it isn't accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can not interact with windowed elements [prompts, alerts, etc] with JavaScript.